# LFTP to mirror and exclude

Tags: php, linux, lftp

I'm using LFTP in a script called by PHP, to sync files between my local drive and my webspace using reverse mirror. This works:

```
lftp sftp://user:pass@host-p 22 -e 'set sftp:connect-program "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -a -x -i /home/.ssh/yourkey.key"; 
mirror -eRv --delete /media/sparky/Artwork/Web/Sites/space-art.co.uk/ /spaceart; quit;'
```

But when I try to exclude certain folders/files, it systematically deletes all my files on the remote server. I used this:

```
    lftp sftp://user:pass@host-p 22 -e 'set sftp:connect-program "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -a -x -i /home/.ssh/yourkey.key"; 
mirror -eRv 
--exclude .vscode/ 
--exclude *.clpprj
--exclude *.scprj
--exclude database/scripts/ 
--delete /media/sparky/Artwork/Web/Sites/space-art.co.uk/ /spaceart; quit;'
```

I call the above script using this:

```
$output = shell_exec("/media/sparky/Artwork/Web/Sites/markgarlick.com/database/scripts/.sync-spaceart.sh") or die ("Error syncing to space-art.co.uk");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it work when you run it in a shell, without PHP? How is it related to PHP? Please share the relevant PHP code if you run it through PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Haven't tried running it in a shell. The whole point is to update and sync my websites all within PHP. I use this:

$output = shell_exec("/media/sparky/Artwork/Web/Sites/markgarlick.com/database/scripts/.sync-spaceart.sh") or die ("Error synching to space-art.co.uk");

Comment: Please **Edit** the question and add this code into it.